# Questions to support vector regression following recursive feature elimination

Tags: cross-validation, svm

Among 55 features, a recursive feature elimination (RFE) selected 15 important features using a support vector regression (SVR) estimator, cross-validation (kfold = 5) and gridsearch (kfold = 5). Best estimator was based on C = 0.01 and revealed an r2 score of 0.25.

My questions:

1. Subsequently, and to test, I've expected a similar r2 score when running a SVR, again with gridsearchCV (k = 5) only with those 15 features selected from the RFE. However, in contrast to the above RFE analysis, I received a much higher r2 score of 0.44. Furthermore, the best estimator was not C = 0.01 but C = 0.1.

   Can someone please explain the possible reasons for this huge discrepancy?
2. The coef_ attribute from the SVR reveals the weights of each feature. Some features have a weight above 0.5, some are negative. How can I interpret those weights? Do positive weights demonstrate a positive "correlation" with the target variable and negative ones would indicate an inverse relationship? (E.g. a higher score of the feature would predict a lower target variable ?)

Comment: Please explain your TLAs, which otherwise might be read in an ambiguous manner.

Comment: thanks, I would. What are TLAs ?

Comment: That's precisely my point: your use of three-letter acronyms (TLAs), like "SVR" and "RFE," is opaque.  Please spell them out on first use.

Comment: I see! modified accordingly. thx